# Given two INTs how do I combine them into a single BIGINT in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Right now all I can think of is:

```
DECLARE @x INT = 0x123
DECLARE @y INT = 0x456
DECLARE @z BIGINT = @x * CAST(4294967296 AS BIGINT) + @y
PRINT CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), @z)
```

Which indeed prints 0x0000012300000456

But my question is about `@x * CAST(4294967296 AS BIGINT) + @y`. This seems a bit awkward and if it is implemented as a real multiplication then it is truly inefficient (even though insignificant against the big scheme of things)

So, is it the way to do it in Sql Server 2012?

**EDIT 1**

I need to combine them any 1-1 way. I am interested in the most efficient code. Obviously, this is purely academic, since I do not anticipate any performance issues because of the way I am going to do it.

Comment: It's not really clear how you intend to combine two signed integers? Something like `SELECT CAST(CAST(@x AS BINARY(4)) +  CAST(@y AS BINARY(4)) AS BIGINT)`

Comment: @MartinSmith - please, see my **EDIT 1**. Out of curiosity, what is more efficient - multiplying by `4294967296` or doing it your way?

Answer (score 3):

my research (to get combined column of two int columns, datatype of combined column is no matter for me) on big table (24M+ rows):
CONCAT vs "multiplication and sum"
results in 6914 vs 5645 milliseconds

```
SELECT CONCAT(int1,'_',int2) b ...
SELECT CAST(ISNULL(int1,0) AS BIGINT)*4294967296 + ISNULL(int2,0) b ...
```